# Apache mod_rewrite specificity: modules stops at most generic RewriteRule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with specificity of rules in Apache mod_rewrite where the rewrite module stops at the first occurence of a rule and ignores more specific ones:

```
RewriteRule ^manuals static/manuals.html [END,NC]
RewriteRule ^manuals/manual_1 static/manual_1.html [END,NC]
```

If I visit manuals/ I correctly see page manuals.html but if I visit manuals/manual_1 I get again the manuals.html page.
How can I modify the above to observe the most specific matching instead of stopping at first partial match?

Comment: Well, yes, the first matching rule wins. Put your generic catch-alls after the more specific rules.

Comment: Yes.  Simply reverse the order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix it by using regex anchors `^` and `$` in your rules:

```
RewriteRule ^manuals/?$ static/manuals.html [END,NC]
RewriteRule ^manuals/manual_1/?$ static/manual_1.html [END,NC]
```